# How to use Request::user() inside a controller in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm developing this to store users "Orders" in a batch.
My doubt is: How do I request user data inside the OrderController `store()`
I already debugged this and `$id_user` is `null`, probably because I'm already using `Request::get` for the form data.
I could pass the `$id_user` from the form inputs, but I guess it's not secure.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {               
        $quantities = Request::get('quantity');
        $products = Request::get('id_product');
        $hash_card = Request::get('hash_card');

        $user = Request::user();
        $id_user = $user->id_user;

        $total_products = count($products);


        for($i=0;$i<$total_products;$i++){ 

            if($quantities[$i]>0){ 

                $id_product = $products[$i];
                $quantity = $quantities[$i];

                $product=Product::find($id_product); 
                $product_price=$product->price;  

                $order_data[] = [
                                'id_user' => $id_user, 
                                'id_product' => $id_product,
                                'quantity' => $quantity,
                                'product_price' => $product_price,
                                'hash_card' => $hash_card
                                ];  
            }
        }

        Order::insert($order_data);  

        return redirect('pedidos?add&card='.$hash_card);   

    }
```

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have debugging on, by any chance? Because this script shouldn't run at all. You shouldn't be able to call the method statically.

Try this:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{               
    $quantities = $request->quantity;
    $products = $request->id_product;
    $hash_card = $request->hash_card;

    $id_user = $request->user()->id;

    $total_products = count($products);


    for($i=0;$i<$total_products;$i++){ 

        if($quantities[$i]>0){ 

            $id_product = $products[$i];
            $quantity = $quantities[$i];

            $product=Product::find($id_product); 
            $product_price=$product->price;  

            $order_data[] = [
                            'id_user' => $id_user, 
                            'id_product' => $id_product,
                            'quantity' => $quantity,
                            'product_price' => $product_price,
                            'hash_card' => $hash_card
                            ];  
        }
    }

    Order::insert($order_data);  

    return redirect('pedidos?add&card='.$hash_card);   

}
```